# How to pass arguments to hiltViewModel() with HorizontalPager?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt

I'm making the Compose application that shows many pages in one screen. I want to use `HorizontalPager` with my ViewModel instance for each page. E.g.

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class ListViewModel 
@Inject constructor(
    val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
    ): ViewModel(){
   
    /* Database query in real application */
    val ids = flow {
                listOf(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
       }

@Composable
fun ListScreen(viewModel: ListViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val myIds: List<Int> by viewModel.ids.collectAsState(emptyList())

    HorizontalPager(
      pageCount = myIds.size,
     ) { index ->
      PageScreen(myIds[index])
     }
}

@HiltViewModel
class PageViewModel 
@Inject constructor(
    val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
): ViewModel() {
     /* HOW to get here id for this page? */
}

@Composable
fun PageScreen(
     id: Int,
     viewModel: PageViewModel = hiltViewModel() // How to pass id to hiltViewModel?
) {
    /* ..... */
}
```

I know that `savedStateHandle` can contain navigation arguments when I use the navigation. How I can pass arguments when I use `HorizontalPager`?

Thanks.

Comment: have you solved that?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `savedStateHandle` can contain navigation arguments and this is done with help of [`CreationExtras`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories#creationextras). See how creation extras are used by `Fragment` [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/refs/heads/androidx-master-dev/fragment/fragment/src/main/java/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.java#484).

```java
    public CreationExtras getDefaultViewModelCreationExtras() {
        ...
        MutableCreationExtras extras = new MutableCreationExtras();
        if (application != null) {
            extras.set(ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.APPLICATION_KEY, application);
        }
        extras.set(SavedStateHandleSupport.SAVED_STATE_REGISTRY_OWNER_KEY, this);
        extras.set(SavedStateHandleSupport.VIEW_MODEL_STORE_OWNER_KEY, this);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            extras.set(SavedStateHandleSupport.DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY, getArguments());
        }
        return extras;
    }
```

Later `CreationExtras.createSavedStateHandle()` is called and arguments finally appear in saved state handle instance which is passed to a view model.

---

The idea with `HorizontalPager` is to supply required arguments manually via custom `CreationExtras`. Such argument is exposed in `viewModel()` composable.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListScreen(viewModel: ListViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val myIds: List<Int> by viewModel.ids.collectAsState(emptyList())

    HorizontalPager(pageCount = myIds.size) { index ->
        val args = bundleOf("id" to myIds[index])
        PageScreen(
            viewModel = viewModel(
                extras = MutableCreationExtras().apply {
                    set(DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY, args)
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

But this won't be enough because other `SavedStateHandleSupport` keys are required for creation of a saved state handle. This means that we need to mutate existing default creation extras.

This is a custom version of `viewModel()` composable that calculates default creation extras and allows a caller to mutate them.

```kotlin
@Composable
inline fun <reified VM : ViewModel> viewModel(
    viewModelStoreOwner: ViewModelStoreOwner = checkNotNull(LocalViewModelStoreOwner.current) {
        "No ViewModelStoreOwner was provided via LocalViewModelStoreOwner"
    },
    key: String? = null,
    factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory? = null,
    updateExtras: MutableCreationExtras.() -> Unit
): VM {
    val defaultExtras = if (viewModelStoreOwner is HasDefaultViewModelProviderFactory) {
        viewModelStoreOwner.defaultViewModelCreationExtras
    } else {
        CreationExtras.Empty
    }
    val extras = MutableCreationExtras(defaultExtras).apply(updateExtras)
    return viewModel(VM::class.java, viewModelStoreOwner, key, factory, extras)
}
```

Finally, a horizontal pager composable will look like this:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun ListScreen(viewModel: ListViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {
    val myIds: List<Int> by viewModel.ids.collectAsState(emptyList())

    HorizontalPager(pageCount = myIds.size) { index ->
        val args = bundleOf("id" to myIds[index])
        PageScreen(
            viewModel = viewModel(
                updateExtras = {
                    set(DEFAULT_ARGS_KEY, args)
                }
            )
        )
    }
}
```

NOTE: I used `viewModel()` instead of `hiltViewModel()` here because this was a case I faced with. But with this understanding you may try to solve your case.